# How to keep horizantal scroll bar only for One particular column in a table?

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, datagridviewcolumn

Lets say I have a table with three columns, I want to keep horizantal scroll bar only for the third column. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use overflow-x for that.

Like this:

```css
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 200px;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
}

td:nth-child(3)
{
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>bbbbbbbbbb</td>
    <td>cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I needed one scroll bar for entire column, Try keeping two rows and check, It will give scroll bar for each row.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a combination of css bits and bobs...

---

**Named Cells Only Scroll**

```
<table class='a-table'>
<tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th></tr>

<tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td class='different'>Three-million-one-hundred-and-sixty-eight sausages marched in unison</td></tr>

</table>
```

With this particular example, I've designated the column as a specific class, as we seem to want one column to behave differently from the others.

I've also set a fixed width to the cells, just to make this work in the example, and added `white-space: nowrap;` to force the contents to expand horizontally, rather than the default behaviour of wrapping onto a new line to prevent scrolling

```
.a-table {
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
.a-table td {
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.different {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Feel free to use `overflow: auto` instead of `scroll` if you only want to show the scroll bar *if* it's required.

It's worth noting that one of the other answers uses `overflow: hidden`, which will probably exhibit unwanted behaviour if any of your other cells have contents which exceed the set width, whereas this example will wrap as normal.

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xpfz8ho4/

---

**Each Cell In a Column with Scroll**

For multi-row tables, this solution will also enforce the behaviour on an entire column:

CSS:

```
.a-table {
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
.a-table td {
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.a-table td:nth-child(3) {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class='a-table'>
<tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th></tr>

<tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three-million-one-hundred-and-sixty-eight sausages marched in unison</td></tr>
<tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three-million-one-hundred-and-sixty-eight sausages marched in unison</td></tr>

</table>
```

Example Fiddle of this:
https://jsfiddle.net/w9a1kcmt/

---

**Scroll entire Column**

This is possible, but gets a bit trickier.

For this, I have enclosed my table within a `div`, which I'm calling **tableinside**.   I also state my fixed (non-scolling) columns as **fixed**

```
<div class='tableinside'>
  <table class='a-table'>
  <tr><th class='fixed'>One</th><th class='fixed'>Two</th><th>Three</th></tr>

  <tr><td class='fixed'>One</td><td class='fixed'>Two</td><td>Three-million-one-hundred-and-sixty-eight sausages marched in unison</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='fixed'>One</td><td class='fixed'>Two</td><td>Three-million-one-hundred-and-sixty-eight sausages marched in unison</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Now, the CSS comes in.  In reality, we are going to shift our static columns outside of the `<div>`, meaning only the whole third column is actually positioned within the div.

This means we need to make the div have a `margin-left` equal to the sum of the width of all the static columns, which is 100px in this case, with some adjustment made for margins of 5px, so 110px total.  Then, we'll make the same adjustments for each of the static columns:

```
.a-table td, th {
            border: 1px solid #ccc; 
            white-space: nowrap;
}
.tableinside { 
            width: 300px; 
            overflow-x:scroll;  
            margin-left:110px; 
}
.fixed {
         position:absolute; 
         width:50px; 
         left:10px;
         top:auto;
        }
.fixed:nth-child(2) {
          margin-left: 55px;
}
```

This all comes together like this https://jsfiddle.net/ruttgj79/

Of course you'd have to do a bit of tidying up with the CSS, but that's a way of getting this concept to work.

Comment: Here you have specified class 'different' for each cell of a column not for the whole column. You can try keeping one more row and check what I am saying.

Comment: For an entire column, remove the class and specify the nth-child instead

https://jsfiddle.net/w9a1kcmt/

Comment: I guess I am not clear with the requirement..the example you shown will give scroll for each row..I am hoping for only one scroll bar for entire column..

Comment: I have updated my answer based on what you have described